# Weebly button broken

Tags: html, forms, button, weebly

I am trying to get the log in button to work pressing enter in either field posts the form and the button appears but does nothing. Here is the code, any ideas?
Thanks a bunch in advance!

```
<div><form id="login" action="" method="POST">
<div id="login-form-parent" class="wsite-form-container" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-right: 0px; margin">
<h2 class="wsite-content-title" style="text-align: center;">
<span style="font-size: large;">Please enter your credentials</span></h2>
<div>
<div style= "text-align: center";>
<label class="wsite-form-label" for="name">Username</label>
<div>
<input id="input-616817079299148233" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input wsite-input-width-370px" name="username" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
<div>
<div style="text-align: center";>
<label class="wsite-form-label" for="password">Password</label>
<div>
<input id="input-984837360768012607" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input wsite-input-width-370px" name="pwd" type="password" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"><input name="wsite_subject" type="text" />
</div>
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
<input name="form_version" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input id="wsite-approved" name="wsite_approved" type="hidden" value="approved" /> 
<input name="ucfid" type="hidden" value="login" />
<input style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;" type="submit" />
<a class="wsite-button">
<span class="wsite-button-inner">Submit</span></a></div>
</form></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

there's no action linked to the form.. fill in action=" " linking to your log in php page.

Comment: Wouldn't that stop the log in script from working at all? I currently can log in just not using the button.

Comment: how is that possible, u're using a form which isn't attached to any sort of php code to log you in.

Comment: The php script captures the log in details of the form, any ideas on the button?

Answer (score 0):

You would need some handler using jQuery from .wsite-button-inner to trigger your `<input type="sumbmit">`. Since you hid your input button off screen. When using java script to handle it to have a fancy button best practice would be to add JavaScript validation (not shown in code).

Ie: `document.getElementById("login").submit();`

or

```js
function submitform()
{
  document.login.submit();
}
```

```html
<div><form id="login" action="" method="POST">
<div id="login-form-parent" class="wsite-form-container" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-right: 0px; margin">
<h2 class="wsite-content-title" style="text-align: center;">
<span style="font-size: large;">Please enter your credentials</span></h2>
<div>
<div style= "text-align: center";>
<label class="wsite-form-label" for="name">Username</label>
<div>
<input id="input-616817079299148233" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input wsite-input-width-370px" name="username" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
<div>
<div style="text-align: center";>
<label class="wsite-form-label" for="password">Password</label>
<div>
<input id="input-984837360768012607" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input wsite-input-width-370px" name="pwd" type="password" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"><input name="wsite_subject" type="text" />
</div>
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
<input name="form_version" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input id="wsite-approved" name="wsite_approved" type="hidden" value="approved" /> 
<input name="ucfid" type="hidden" value="login" />
<input style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;" type="submit" />
<a href="javascript: submitform()" class="wsite-button">
<span class="wsite-button-inner">Submit</span></a></div>
</form></div>
```

Inline html:

```html
<div><form id="login" action="" method="POST">
<div id="login-form-parent" class="wsite-form-container" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-right: 0px; margin">
<h2 class="wsite-content-title" style="text-align: center;">
<span style="font-size: large;">Please enter your credentials</span></h2>
<div>
<div style= "text-align: center";>
<label class="wsite-form-label" for="name">Username</label>
<div>
<input id="input-616817079299148233" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input wsite-input-width-370px" name="username" type="text" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 15px;"></div>
<div>
<div style="text-align: center";>
<label class="wsite-form-label" for="password">Password</label>
<div>
<input id="input-984837360768012607" class="wsite-form-input wsite-input wsite-input-width-370px" name="pwd" type="password" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"><input name="wsite_subject" type="text" />
</div>
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
<input name="form_version" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input id="wsite-approved" name="wsite_approved" type="hidden" value="approved" /> 
<input name="ucfid" type="hidden" value="login" />
<input style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;" type="submit" />
<a href="javascript: submitform()" class="wsite-button">
<span class="wsite-button-inner">Submit</span></a></div>
</form></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
document.login.submit();
}
</script>
```